# How to calibrate a Mac Monitor for iPhone development

Tags: iphone, monitor, gamma

How to calibrate a Mac monitor to match the iPhone's colours?

What is the iPhone's gamma?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this article](http://www.colorwiki.com/wiki/Color_on_iPhone), the gamma is 1.8, which is what Mac OSX Leopard was. Snow Leopard is now 2.2, similar to Windows gamma settings. I recently designed a iPhone app on Leopard and it's comparable to it running on the iPhone. What I recommend you do to be safe is export your design to a png and load it into an ImageView in interface builder. Then you can "quick compile" that and preview it on your phone or simulator. There's no better test for iPhone apps than being installed on the device.

Comment: Great, thanks. When in Leopard, did you notice some color diference between the iPhone and your Mac? For example: the iPhone was more red... or the greens were lighter etc.?

Comment: No, looks the same to me since leopard and iphone's gammas are the same. Keep in mind your monitor's individual settings can override the system defaults, so, as I said, best to preview on your device.

Comment: I understand. On what iPhone did you test? I've read that the 3GS is brighter than the other iPhones. I am suspecting that the 3GS has a 2.2 gamma, just like Snow Leopard..

Comment: I have a 3gs and a "2" Never tested on the "2"

Comment: Thanks, great information, that helps me a lot. So the 3GS and Leopard have a similar gamma. I'll base my designs on a 1.8 gamma.

Answer (score 0):

Although, not specifically asked...  Under the broader topic of: "how do more closely reperesent the look/feel of the iPhone on the desktop screen".

I recently stumbled onto a great addition when I changed machines to the newer high res 17" MacBookPro (on the desktop, basically as my second monitor). While code on the crazy tiny pixels is not so great, it does give me a much closer approximation to the way things will look on the iPhone simulator.

Just thought I'd pass it along (and I'm too new to comment).   :-)